# I get 'QgsVectorLayer: 'New CSV' (Invalid)' using pyQGIs library, QgsVectorLayer in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, qgis, pyqgis

I have multiple csv files with different sizes. I used the below code to extract two columns 'X' & 'Y'. and concatenate files to make a file with only mentioned columns. In the next step, I save it with .to_csv to somewhere in my pc. You can see the code below.

```
pathcsv = 'C:/Users/xdy-4yh/OneDrive/Desktop/PSInew'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(pathcsv , "*.csv"))
li = []
for filename in all_files:
    selcCol = ['X', 'Y']
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols = selcCol)
    li.append(df)
crslst=[]
points = pd.concat(li, axis=0)
#for iii in range(len(points)):
points.to_csv('C:/Users/xdy-4yh/OneDrive/Desktop/AutoDownloadLODfiles/read a shapefiel/pointsss.csv', 
              index=True , sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

Next, I used the address above 'C:/Users/xdy-4yh/OneDrive/Desktop/AutoDownloadLODfiles/read a shapefiel/pointsss.csv' to build a URI for QgsVectorLayer and load the csv file as Layer in jupyter.
However, the problem is after running the code, I got <QgsVectorLayer: 'New CSV' (Invalid)>.

```
uri = "file:///C:/Users/xdy-4yh/OneDrive/Desktop/AutoDownloadLODfiles/read a shapefiel/pointsss.csv?delimiter=%s&crs=epsg:25832&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (",", "X", "Y")
lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'New CSV','delimitedtext')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

PS1: I also import below libraries:

`QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.26.3", True)  QgsApplication( [], False ) app = QtWidgets.QApplication([]) QgsApplication.initQgis()`

PS2: I have also used QgsVectorLayer for Shapefile and it was okay. see below:

```
Processing.initialize()

path = 'C:/Users/xdy-4yh/OneDrive/Desktop/LOD2/*.shp'
Save_results = 'C:/Users/xdy-4yh/OneDrive/Desktop/merged/'
file = glob.glob(path)
pathnew = [os.path.join(path, i) for i in file if "shp" in i]
processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':pathnew,'CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:25832')
                                            ,'OUTPUT':Save_results+'mergedlod.shp'})
## load merged layer
lod2merged = QgsVectorLayer('C:/Users/xdy-4yh/OneDrive/Desktop/merged','mergedlod','ogr')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lod2merged, True)
```

Thank you for helping me :)